# SQL Server full outer joins multiple disconnected tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server so request you to not get offended by silly question.

I have six disjointed tables (table1, table2 (two columns to be queried), table3, table4, table5, table6 (This is child table of table 5)) in my database.

These are dissimilar tables and I want to use single query to search data from one column in each table  and if found then it populate in rows.

I am running following query

```
 SELECT 
     table1.*
     , table2.*
     , table3.*
     , table4.*
     , table5.*
     , table6.*
FROM
    dbo.table1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col_A OR table1.col1 = table2.col_B
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.table3 ON table2.col_A = table3.col_F OR table2.col_B = table3.col_F
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.table4 ON table3.col_F = table4.col_I
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.table5 ON table4.col_I = table5.col_N
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.table6 ON table5.col_N = table6.col_U OR table5.col_N = table6.col_V
WHERE
    table1.col1 LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
    OR table2.col_A LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
    OR table2.col_B LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
    OR table3.col_F LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
    OR table4.col_I LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
    OR table5.col_N LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
```

However I am not getting results from all the tables. But when I run individually I get correct results. For example

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE
       table1.col1 LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'

SELECT table5.* , table6.*
FROM
   dbo.table5
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.table6 ON table5.col_N = table6.col_U OR table5.col_N = table6.col_V
WHERE
   table5.col_N LIKE '%' + USERINPUT + '%'
```

All help appreciated to solve the issue. In short want to have single query that runs across all the table and bring out matching rows ONLY

Comment: Why is the last join an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are using `full outer join`, but the conditions require matches.

For instance, consider the join to `table4`:

```
ON table3.col_F = table4.col_I
```

Well, to get any matching row from `Table4`, you have to have a non-`NULL` value in `table3.col_F`.  But, because of the `full outer join`, there are likely to be many `NULL` values.  This doesn't quite turn the structure into `inner join`, but it does end up with many `table4` values on their own row, with all the other values being `NULL`.

Unless you really know what you are doing, you probably do not need `full outer join`s.  Sometimes, you can re-phrase this type of query as a `union all` with an aggregation or just use `left join` or `inner join` instead.